# Owner update OTRS

Tags: php, soap, otrs

I am having trouble updating owner as well as updating tickets. I am using soap api in PHP. 
i am using OTRS 3.1.12.
i tried using following.

```
 $url      = "https://url/otrs/rpc.pl";  // URL for OTRS server
            $username = "username";  // SOAP username set in sysconfig
            $password = "password";  // SOAP password set in sysconfig

        ### Form Fields

        $new_owner =$_POST['new_owner'];
        $subject =$_POST['subject'];
        $text = $_POST['text'];
        $note_type = $_POST['note_type'];


        #### Initialize new client session ####
        $client = new SoapClient(
            null,
            array(
                'location'  => $url,
                'uri'       => "Core",
                'trace'     => 1,
                'login'     => $username,
                'password'  => $password,
                'style'     => SOAP_RPC,
                'use'       => SOAP_ENCODED
            )
        );

        #### Create a new ticket shell. The function returns the Ticket ID ####
        $TicketID = $client->__soapCall(
            "Dispatch", array($username, $password,
                "TicketObject", "TicketCreate",
                "TicketID",       $ticket_id,
                "OwnerID",      $new_owner,
                "UserID",       1,
            )
        );

        ##### Create an article with the info. The function returns an Article ID ####
        $ArticleID = $client->__soapCall("Dispatch",
            array($username, $password,
                "TicketObject",   "ArticleCreate",
                "Subject",        $subject,
                "ContentType",    "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
                "Body",           $text,

            )
        );
```

This is completely wrong i know. Can anyone help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$URL = 'https://your-url.com/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/WebserviceName'; //webserviceName is the name of webservice created from admin panel of otrs
$namespace = 'https://your-url.com/otrs/GenericInterface/actions'; //namespace of soap config

$username = "username"; //// SOAP username set in sysconfig
$password = "password"; //// SOAP password set in sysconfig

// initialize a SoapClient instance
$SOAPClientInstance = new \SoapClient(null, array(
'location'=> $URL,
'uri' => $namespace,
'trace' => 1,
'login' => $username,
'password'=> $password,
'style' => SOAP_RPC,
'use' => SOAP_ENCODED,

)
);


// set the request parameters as an array of SoapParam instances
$TicketRequestArray = array(

new \SoapParam('username', 'UserLogin'), //user username
new \SoapParam('password', "Password"),// user password
);

$TicketRequestArray[] = new \SoapParam('123', 'TicketID');// ID of ticket which is to be updated
$TicketRequestArray[] = new \SoapParam(array(
'State' => 'open',
'OwnerID' => $new_owner, // you can add which parameters to update
), 'Ticket');
$Action = 'TicketUpdate';

$Response = $SOAPClientInstance->__soapCall($Action,
$TicketRequestArray
);

print "<pre>\n";
print "Request :\n".htmlspecialchars($SOAPClientInstance->__getLastRequest()) ."\n";
print "Response:\n".htmlspecialchars($SOAPClientInstance->__getLastResponse())."\n";
print "</pre>";
```